# Latex error: \begin{appendices} ended by \end{document}

Tags: tables, appendices

Everything is normal, until I inserted a table in Appendix as

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \makeatletter
    \let\@fnsymbol\@arabic
    \makeatother
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=40mm
 }
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mcases}[1][l]
 {\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}#1@{}}}
 {\endarray\right.}
\makeatother

% Swap the definition of \abs* and \norm*, so that \abs
% and \norm resizes the size of the brackets, and the 
% starred version does not.
\makeatletter
\let\oldabs\abs
\def\abs{\@ifstar{\oldabs}{\oldabs*}}
%
\let\oldnorm\norm
\def\norm{\@ifstar{\oldnorm}{\oldnorm*}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\doublespacing
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\fontsize{9}{10.8}\itshape} 
\topmargin 0.0cm
\oddsidemargin 0.2cm
\textwidth 16cm 
\textheight 21cm
\footskip 1.0cm
\setlength{\affilsep}{0em}
\begin{document}
XXXXX




\begin{appendices}
\section{XX1}
xxxxxx
\section{XX2}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{some caption}
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
\caption{some caption}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\hline
$\hat{\tau}$ & $\hat{P}(\hat{\tau}|\bm{D})$ & $r_{T,\tau}$\\
\hline
$\ast\tau$& 0.998& 1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
\caption{some caption}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\hline
$\hat{\tau}$ & $\hat{P}(\hat{\tau}|\bm{D})$ & $r_{T,\tau}$\\
\hline
$\ast\tau$&0.992& 0.998\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}
\normalsize\doublespace
\small \singlespace
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

When I remove the table, everything is normal. The table is copied from the previous place of the file, and it works normally there. What is the problem with this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the lines `\normalsize\doublespace \small \singlespace` it will compile correctly. They have really no sense in this context.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Why the lines caused the problem? I used the lines outside Appendix environment to control the distance.

Comment: If you want to add space, you should use `\vspace`. You should accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: You're right about the fact that the removed lines are not really useful but you missed the explanation: `doublespace` is an environment, not an 'ordinary' macro, so the compilation fails because `\enddoublespace` or better: `\end{doublespace}` is never called, the same is true for `\singlespace

Comment: @ChristianHupfer then why \singlespace does not cause troubles out side Appendix environment?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer Thank you for giving this important explanation.

Comment: @bmv: I have to check actually.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer CTAN says that `doublespace` environment is obsolete. The `setspace` package should be used, with `\doublespacing` and `\singlespacing`.

Comment: @bmv: Yes... some even say that `setspace` shouldn't be used ;-)